# Drawing a binary tree in Java-How to call functions

Tags: java, swing, awt, binary-tree

I have tree classes and i try to draw a binary tree in java using JPanel. Without a main method i can not run it. What do i have to write in main method to call functions to draw tree?

```
<!--language:Java-->
package binarytreepanel;

public interface BinaryTreeNode<E> {

    /**
     * Returns the data stored in this node.
     */
    E getData();

    /**
     * Modifies the data stored in this node.
     */
    void setData(E data);

    /**
     * Returns the parent of this node, or null if this node is a root.
     */
    BinaryTreeNode<E> getParent();

    /**
     * Returns the left child of this node, or null if it does
     * not have one.
     */
    BinaryTreeNode<E> getLeft();

    /**
     * Removes child from its current parent and inserts it as the
     * left child of this node.  If this node already has a left
     * child it is removed.
     * 
     * @exception IllegalArgumentException if the child is
     * an ancestor of this node, since that would make
     * a cycle in the tree.
     */
    void setLeft(BinaryTreeNode<E> child);

    /**
     * Returns the right child of this node, or null if it does
     * not have one.
     */
    BinaryTreeNode<E> getRight();

    /**
     * Removes child from its current parent and inserts it as the
     * right child of this node.  If this node already has a right
     * child it is removed.
     * @exception IllegalArgumentException if the child is
     * an ancestor of this node, since that would make
     * a cycle in the tree.
     */
    void setRight(BinaryTreeNode<E> child);

    /**
     * Removes this node, and all its descendants, from whatever
     * tree it is in.  Does nothing if this node is a root.
     */
    void removeFromParent();

    /**
     * Visits the nodes in this tree in preorder.
     */
    void traversePreorder(Visitor visitor);

    /**
     * Visits the nodes in this tree in postorder.
     */
    void traversePostorder(Visitor visitor);

    /**
     * Visits the nodes in this tree in inorder.
     */
    void traverseInorder(Visitor visitor);

    /**
     * Simple visitor interface.
     */
    public interface Visitor {
        <E> void visit(BinaryTreeNode<E> node);
    }
}
```

Second Class

```
package binarytreepanel;


public class LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E> implements BinaryTreeNode<E> {
    protected E data;
    protected LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E> parent;
    protected LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E> left;
    protected LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E> right;

    /**
     * Constructs a node as the root of its own one-element tree.
     * This is the only public constructor.  The only trees that
     * clients can make directly are simple one-element trees.
     */
    public LinkedBinaryTreeNode(E data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the data stored in this node.
     */
    public E getData() {
        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Modifies the data stored in this node.
     */
    public void setData(E data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the parent of this node, or null if this node is a root.
     */
    public BinaryTreeNode<E> getParent() {
      return parent;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the left child of this node, or null if it does
     * not have one.
     */
    public BinaryTreeNode<E> getLeft() {
      return left;
    }

    /**
     * Removes child from its current parent and inserts it as the
     * left child of this node.  If this node already has a left
     * child it is removed.
     * @exception IllegalArgumentException if the child is
     * an ancestor of this node, since that would make
     * a cycle in the tree.
     */
    public void setLeft(BinaryTreeNode<E> child) {
        // Ensure the child is not an ancestor.
        for (LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E> n = this; n != null; n = n.parent) {
            if (n == child) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }

        // Ensure that the child is an instance of LinkedBinaryTreeNode.
        LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E> childNode = (LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E>)child;

        // Break old links, then reconnect properly.
        if (this.left != null) {
            left.parent = null;
        }
        if (childNode != null) {
            childNode.removeFromParent();
            childNode.parent = this;
        }
        this.left = childNode;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the right child of this node, or null if it does
     * not have one.
     */
    public BinaryTreeNode<E> getRight() {
      return right;
    }

    /**
     * Removes child from its current parent and inserts it as the
     * right child of this node.  If this node already has a right
     * child it is removed.
     * @exception IllegalArgumentException if the child is
     * an ancestor of this node, since that would make
     * a cycle in the tree.
     */
    public void setRight(BinaryTreeNode<E> child) {
        // Ensure the child is not an ancestor.
        for (LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E> n = this; n != null; n = n.parent) {
            if (n == child) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }

        // Ensure that the child is an instance of LinkedBinaryTreeNode.
        LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E> childNode = (LinkedBinaryTreeNode<E>)child;

        // Break old links, then reconnect properly.
        if (right != null) {
            right.parent = null;
        }
        if (childNode != null) {
            childNode.removeFromParent();
            childNode.parent = this;
        }
        this.right = childNode;
    }

    /**
     * Removes this node, and all its descendants, from whatever
     * tree it is in.  Does nothing if this node is a root.
     */
    public void removeFromParent() {
        if (parent != null) {
            if (parent.left == this) {
                parent.left = null;
            } else if (parent.right == this) {
                parent.right = null;
            }
            this.parent = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Visits the nodes in this tree in preorder.
     */
    public void traversePreorder(BinaryTreeNode.Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
        if (left != null) left.traversePreorder(visitor);
        if (right != null) right.traversePreorder(visitor);
    }

    /**
     * Visits the nodes in this tree in postorder.
     */
    public void traversePostorder(Visitor visitor) {
        if (left != null) left.traversePostorder(visitor);
        if (right != null) right.traversePostorder(visitor);
        visitor.visit(this);
    }

    /**
     * Visits the nodes in this tree in inorder.
     */
    public void traverseInorder(Visitor visitor) {
        if (left != null) left.traverseInorder(visitor);
        visitor.visit(this);
        if (right != null) right.traverseInorder(visitor);
    }
}
```

And third class

```
package binarytreepanel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

/**
 * A panel that maintains a picture of a binary tree.
 */
public class BinaryTreePanel extends JPanel {
   private BinaryTreeNode<?> tree;
    private int gridwidth;
    private int gridheight;

    /**
     * Stores the pixel values for each node in the tree.
     */
    private Map<BinaryTreeNode<?>, Point> coordinates =
        new HashMap<BinaryTreeNode<?>, Point>();

    /**
     * Constructs a panel, saving the tree and drawing parameters.
     */
    public BinaryTreePanel(BinaryTreeNode<?> tree, int gridwidth, int gridheight) {
        this.tree = tree;
        this.gridwidth = gridwidth;
        this.gridheight = gridheight;
    }

    /**
     * Changes the tree rendered by this panel.
     */
    public void setTree(BinaryTreeNode<?> root) {
        tree = root;
        repaint();
    }

    /**
     * Draws the tree in the panel.  First it computes the coordinates
     * of all the nodes with an inorder traversal, then draws them
     * with a postorder traversal.
     */
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);


        if (tree == null) {
            return;
        }

        tree.traverseInorder(new BinaryTreeNode.Visitor() {
            private int x = gridwidth;
            public void visit(BinaryTreeNode node) {
                coordinates.put(node, new Point(x, gridheight * (depth(node)+1)));
                x += gridwidth;
            }
        });

        tree.traversePostorder(new BinaryTreeNode.Visitor() {
            public void visit(BinaryTreeNode node) {
                String data = node.getData().toString();
                Point center = (Point)coordinates.get(node);
                if (node.getParent() != null) {
                    Point parentPoint = (Point)coordinates.get(node.getParent());
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.drawLine(center.x, center.y, parentPoint.x, parentPoint.y);
                }
                FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
                Rectangle r = fm.getStringBounds(data, g).getBounds();
                r.setLocation(center.x - r.width/2, center.y - r.height/2);
                Color color = getNodeColor(node);
                Color textColor =
                    (color.getRed() + color.getBlue() + color.getGreen() < 382)
                    ? Color.white
                    : Color.black;
                g.setColor(color);
                g.fillRect(r.x - 2 , r.y - 2, r.width + 4, r.height + 4);
                g.setColor(textColor);
                g.drawString(data, r.x, r.y + r.height);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Returns a color for the node.  If the node is of a class with a
     * field called "color", and that field currently contains a
     * non-null value, then that value is returned.  Otherwise
     * a default color of yellow is returned.
     */
    Color getNodeColor(BinaryTreeNode<?> node) {
        try {
            Field field = node.getClass().getDeclaredField("color");
            return (Color)field.get(node);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Color.yellow;
        }
    }

    private int depth(BinaryTreeNode<?> node) {
        return (node.getParent() == null) ? 0 : 1 + depth(node.getParent());
    }


}
```

Comment: Start by putting a `main` method somewhere and initializing the needed classes. `paintComponent` has already been overridden for you so the painting is taken care of.

Comment: this is what i don`t know how to do. if the painting is solved, what shall i write in main calss?

Comment: I assume this is HW, if so, you should post the exercise and your attempt at solution. Your `main` method can technically go anywhere as long as it has access to the **class it needs to initialize**.

Comment: i can`t figure out which is the class

Comment: any tips for the main method?

Comment: Post the HW instructions.

Comment: This is no HW(homework) if this means. I found these classes on a website and i want to run them, to understand functionality. But i guess the main class is missing and i tried to call as i know but i got one problem. Could not convert string or int or anything to a LIST<?>.

Comment: Initialize a `BinaryTreePanel` in your main with the constructor `BinaryTreePanel(BinaryTreeNode<?> tree, int gridwidth, int gridheight)`.

Comment: tried. Same List<?>-questionmark error.